# Load Gradle plugin from custom plugin, dynamically

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am developing a Gradle plugin (https://github.com/hkhc/jarbird), which apply some other plugins in the code according to different scenarios.

I can do that by putting the plugin components as `implementation` dependencies in my plugin project. Then apply the project with `project.apply()` method with plugin ID or plugin class object.

However, this means unnecessary downloads of plugin components when I don't need those plugins. So I am finding a way to resolve the plugins dynamically.

I tried to do that by adding the dependency as `compileOnly` in the build script of my custom plugin, and load it in `project.apply()` of my plugin.

```
val artifactoryConfiguration = project.buildscript.configurations.detachedConfiguration(
    DefaultExternalModuleDependency(
        "org.jfrog.buildinfo",
        "build-info-extractor-gradle",
        "4.23.4"
    )
)
artifactoryConfiguration.resolve()
```

When I made the coordinate wrong intentionally, I got `ModuleVersionNotFoundException`. So I am sure the resolve did take place. However, `project.apply(ArtifactoryPlugin::class.java)` still cause ClassNotFoundException when executing the plugin. It seems Gradle cannot load the plugin from a random detached configuration.

I got stuck at this point, and don't know how to make Gradle load a plugin that I resolve dynamically in my custom plugin.

Do I get the direction wrong or I missed something that makes this approach work?